# Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter '\n'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am encountering an error while processing the csv file while loading it into snowflake. How do i treat this issue every time i encounter it as there are few records with the same error and I don't want to delete any record from the csv file.
Or how can i implement a try-except here? I want to either correct or skip records in csv with errors

```
import snowflake.connector
tableName='F58155'

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='-',
password='-',
account='-')

cs = ctx.cursor()

ctx.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE STORE_PROFILE_LANDING")
ctx.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA PUBLIC")


ctx.cursor().execute("PUT file:///temp/data/{tableName}/* @%{tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
ctx.cursor().execute("truncate table {tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
ctx.cursor().execute("COPY INTO {tableName} ".format(tableName=tableName, 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY 
= '"', sometimes=','))

ctx.close()
```

Here is the image of line 178 where I am getting the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is explained here. Most common cause of this error is that field value contains the delimiter

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Copy-Error-Message-Field-delimiter-found-while-expecting-record-delimiter-n